# Get .prf file from Jetbrains Webstorm and apply it to listings configuration

Tags: lstlisting, ide, lstdefinestyle

From the [listings doc](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf) it is mentioned that I basically can retrieve a Configuration file for the styling of a language from the IDE and apply it as `lstset` setting:

> ...settings in an IDE and can be defined as a listings style. From
>   version 1.5b of the listings package on these styles are provided as
>   files with the name listings-hlanguagei.prf, hlanguagei is the name of
>   the supported programming language in lowercase letters. So if an user
>   of the listings package wants to use these preferences, she/he can say
>   for example when using Python \input{listings-python.prf}
>   at the end of her/his listings.cfg configuration file as long as the
>   file listings-python.prf resides in the TEX search path. Of course
>   that file can be changed according to the user’s preferences. At the
>   moment there are five such preferences files:
>   1. listings-acm.prf
>   2. listings-bash.prf
>   3. listings-fortran.prf
>   4. listings-lua.prf
>   5. listings-python.prf All contributors are invited to supply more personal preferences

Now I am using Jetbrains IDE called Webstorm, but there is no way near I can find a so called listings-language.prf file. The reason I am doing this is, there is no default styling config for Javascript and I implemented the styling of keywords my own way. But with importing this file I can delete my own listings config. Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: The `listings` documentation is not very clear on this, but there is no automatic way to convert IDE settings into a listings configuration file as far as I know. I think you should read the documentation as 'if you like your IDE settings then you can manually write a configuration file that resembles your own settings'.

Comment: Okay thanks. But that would be a awesome feature to integrate styling settings from the ide into lstset properties. Espacially because lstlistings does not offer many (integrated) language options.